# Is there an equivalent for page.emulateMedia('screen') in Chrome headless print-to-pdf?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer

While saving a webpage as PDF with CSS-styles meant for screen is easily done in Puppeteer using `await page.emulateMedia('screen')`, I couldn't find an equivalent in Chrome's function `chrome --headless --print-to-pdf`. Can someone tell, how to force Chrome to use the screen styles?

Answer (score 0):

```
 await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
 await page.evaluate(() => matchMedia('screen').matches);
```

worked for me

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?